# java Calendar format

Tags: java, date, calendar

Please help me to format properly my String.
I really need to display "10 November 2015" instead of 10/11/2015

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
            textView1.setText(("date after 10 months : " + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
        + now.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-" + now.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
```

Comment: Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: simply use `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(now.getTime())`

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                             .format(new java.util.Date()));
```

Always stay on the safer size specify the Locale.

Comment: It would be better to pass in `now.getTime()`, since OP wants a date 10 months in the future, not today's date. But locale is a good point.

Comment: Exactly it is just an example so that she can make out ways to figure it out well if we people start giving them the exact solution they will never use their brain to learn. :)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use SimleDateFormat as given by other. Use the below string to get desired output.

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

use `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy")`[Read more about SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

here you can use this function:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").parse("10/11/2015"));
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it will give `Sun Oct 11 00:00:00 IST 2015` but see needs `11 October 2015`

Comment: then you will get `java.text.ParseException`

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Apparently you want to get the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, add ten months, and then generate text representing the value of that found date.

```
LocalDate.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )
)
.plus( 
    Period.ofMonths( 10 ) 
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG )
                     .withLocale( Locale.ITALY )
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible `Date` & `Calendar` classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone][2] explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

### Adding to a date

Define the span-of-time you want to add.

```
Period p = Period.ofMonths( 10 ) ;  // Ten months span, unattached to timeline.
```

Add the period to our `LocalDate` to get another `LocalDate`. As an immutable object, `LocalDate` produces a new instance based on the values of the original object.

```
LocalDate later = ld.plus( p ) ;
```

### Generating text

To generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`.

```
String output = later.toString() ;
```

To generate text in a `String` representing the value of our `LocalDate`, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

- Generally best to let *java.time* automatically localize by calling the `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.
- To hard-code a specific format, specify a formatting pattern.

This has been covered many times already, so search Stack Overflow for more discussion and examples.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;   // Or Locale.US, Locale.JAPAN, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG )
                                       .withLocale( l );
String output = later.format( f );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, Is there a reason to prefer the more complex `.plus( Period.ofMonths( 10 ) )` over the simpler `.plusMonths( 10 )`? Apart from the versatility, of course, `Period` will also allow adding, say, 1 year 3 months 14 days, but I didn’t think this was asked for here.

Comment: @OleV.V.  No technical difference, just a matter of taste. In real work, this ten months relates to some important business rule. So I would want to make that explicit and self-documenting in the code by using a separate named variable. For example, `Period treatyWithdrawalNotificationPeriod = Period.ofMonths( 10 ) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the SimpleDateFormat class.

Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: ....and save it in a static field if you're sure it will be used by a single thread.